# MySQL insert statement (insert into table (columns) select statement)

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I am trying to insert values into selected columns of table, but only insert the results of a MySQL statement. the select statement works correctly by itself and returns the results.

when combined with the insert statement it is fails with

```
error incorrect syntax near `dedspgoods`.`case number`.
```

Can anyone assist me with the correct syntax? my erronous syntax is as below:

```
insert into despgoods_alldetails 
  (`case number`, weight, customer, transporttypename) 
values 
( select despgoods.`case number`
       , despgoods.weight
       , despgoods.customer
       , customers.transporttypename 
  from despgoods 
    inner join customers 
      on despgoods.customer = customers.customer )
```

Comment: What is the `SELECT` that works?

Comment: select `despgoods`.`case number`,`despgoods`.`weight`,`despgoods`.`customer`,`customers`.`transporttypename` from despgoods inner join customers on despgoods.`customer`=`customers`.`customer`)

Comment: Please note that each field has got ' ' around them, just does not carry through when submitting comment. Thanks

Comment: It probably has backquotes: `\`weight\`` though, not single quotes: `'weight'`

Comment: you cannot just put everything in quotes. you can put 'case number' inside single quotes but not the values or the names of your columns.

Comment: @Ryan: I edited your question. Check that this is what you have.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If this is the `SELECT` that works:

```
select despgoods.`case number`
     , despgoods.weight
     , despgoods.customer
     , customers.transporttypename 
from despgoods 
  inner join customers 
    on despgoods.customer = customers.customer
```

Then try this (notice there is no `VALUES` clause if you want to insert the result set of a `SELECT`:

```
insert into despgoods_alldetails 
  (`case number`, weight, customer, transporttypename) 
select despgoods.`case number`
     , despgoods.weight
     , despgoods.customer
     , customers.transporttypename 
from despgoods 
  inner join customers 
    on despgoods.customer = customers.customer
```

Comment: Hi @ypercube. Thanks a million, syntax works perfectly. apprecaite the help.

Comment: Just note that with `INSERT INTO` you **either** use `VALUES` with a list of rows **or** a `SELECT`.

Comment: And try not have have spaces in the table or column names. You can use `case_number` or `CaseNumber`. It makes it easier as you don't have to backquote it every time.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @EdHeal, you'll need to enclose `case number` between quotes or backticks as there is a space in the column name (the fact that `CASE` is a reserved word is actually only an interesting detail, but that's not what breaks the query in this case).

```
insert into despgoods_alldetails (`case number`,weight,customer,transporttypename) 
values (
    select despgoods.`case number`, despgoods.weight, despgoods.customer, customers.transporttypename
    from despgoods 
    inner join customers on (despgoods.customer=customers.customer)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`case` is a reserved word. Need to put 'case number' in quotes.

Comment: hi, I am insert ` ` arround the fields, the formatting is not included when i submit the comment

Comment: @Ryan: try editing your question. Paste the code into your question, then select it and hit the **Code** icon: **`{}`**. This will format your code as code.

Answer (score 1):

here it goes

```
 INSERT INTO despgoods_alldetails(
                                  casenumber,
                                  weight,
                                  customer,
                                  transporttyplename)


 VALUES(SELECT desp.casenumber,
        desp.weight,
        despgoods.customer, 
        customers.transporttypename)

 FROM despgoods
 INNER JOIN customers on despgoods.customer = customers.customer
```

there. that should work fine. Remember, do not name your variables with spaces, because it can get real tricky. I think you had an error in case number because it has a space in between, when case is a function in MySQL. Let me know if you need anything else.