# i want to insert multiple values from different table in a single table ..

Tags: php, mysql

insert in to `subject_activity_test`
select DISTINCT `activity_id`,`classes`.`id` as `class_id` ,`subject_id` from `truefalse_questions`,`classes`,`chapters`

Comment: create a csv file of the required data and use LOAD file to update the table. This can help you when u want to setup the database only

Comment: insert in to `subject_activity_test` (`activity_id`,`class_id`,`subject_id`)
SELECT DISTINCT `truefalse_questions`.`activity_id`,`classes`.`id` as `class_id` ,`subjects`.`id` as `subject_id` 
from `truefalse_questions`,`classes`,`subjects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO table3 (aID, bID) 
 SELECT A.ID, B.ID 
 FROM table1 A, table2 B 
 WHERE A.Name='Me'
 AND B.Class='Math';
```

Try this.

Use concat function to join two columns example:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (aID, bID) 
SELECT A.ID, concat(A.ID, ' ', B.ID) as bid 
FROM table1 A, table2 B 
WHERE A.Name='Me'
AND B.Class='Math';
```

Comment: i want to get ids of both table in a same column not different columns, you take ids of in two different columns

Answer (score 0):

yes. You can insert record from multiple tables data. for that you have to mention and macth the columns from your insert table and select query.

Check this link for more. [MySQL insert statement (insert into table (columns) select statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709902/mysql-insert-statement-insert-into-table-columns-select-statement)